# How to announce in an ATIS message that two parallel runways are in use?

Tags: atis

Suppose an airport has two parallel runways and aircraft can use any of them.

How would I announce in the ATIS message that both runways are in use?

Comment: Hello Mhmoud, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! I've rephrased your question so that it is easier to understand. Please check if I interpreted your question correctly. If you want to make changes, please use the edit function.

Answer (score 8):

By simply stating that both runways are in use.

For example, "arriving and departing runway 16 left and 16 right."